# Given $\log(n + 1)-1\le h\le\log n$. How does $h$ turn out to be $\lfloor \log n \rfloor$?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was reading through an algorithms book for my CS class, and came across this inequality: $\log(n + 1)-1\le h\le\log n$.

The author concludes with this result: $h = \lfloor \log n \rfloor$

I tried using a property of the floor function from Rosen's book: $ \lfloor x \rfloor = m \iff x-1 \lt m \le x $ and tried considering $ \log n $ as my $x $, but I couldn't reach his result because of the $ +1 $ in my first logarithm.

How did he end up with   $h = \lfloor \log n \rfloor$ ?

Comment: Well it is slightly sloppy. For some values of $n$ it will be wrong. For example for $n=7$ the interval is $[1.08,1.95]$ which does not contain any integers, although 1 is only just outside it. Also fails for $n=20,54$ and no doubt many other values!

Comment: @almagest But the answer (see below) actually reaches Rosen's floor property stated in my question. (@GReyes is basically saying that $ \log n - 1 < log(n+1) - 1\le h \le \log n $.) How come it's generating some wrong values?

Comment: Read it more carefully! It says " **if there is an integer** in the interval" ,,,

Comment: @almagest Oh I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know there is only one integer $h$ with $\log n-1<h\le \log   n$ (namely $\lfloor{\log n}\rfloor$). But clearly $\log (n+1)-1>\log n-1$ so if there is an integer in $[\log (n+1)-1,\log n]$ it has to be $\lfloor{\log n}\rfloor$.